# Need advice to get an approach to do a personalized searcher?

Tags: search

I have a content type called "Flats" which are Flats to sell' each one of them has a 'price' field (ex. 100 000, 150 000, 200 000) and each one has a 'city' field

I need to put a searcher in the home page of the site with 2 selects input, one for 'price range' (with values like 'lower than 100 000', '100 000 to 150 000, ...) and the other for 'city' (with values like: 'Barcelona', 'Madrid', ...)

The searcher should look for flat with prices within the price range and for the chosen city.

A first sight I think I'll need to create an API Form which once submitted should go to a view passing those 2 arguments (price range and city)  in the url as $_GET values.

Is this a right approach to do this? 
Can I use $_GET values as arguments in a view?

Is there any module to do this in a easier way? I don't want to reinvent the wheel...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try a View using exposed filters?  If your content type is made with CCK then you could achieve what you're looking for quite easily.  [This video](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDYQtwIwAw&url=http://yadadrop.com/drupal-video/drupal-views-exposed-filter-1&rct=j&q=drupal%20views%20exposed%20filters&ei=1uYRTqrJKdSIhQeOvKTkDQ&usg=AFQjCNHykX0rfHc5KqZQb1dilE6JQl-Pkw&sig2=JVkxqyHQ4cuoqXdNO6DFaQ&cad=rja) might help you out.  Eric London's [Drupal Blog](http://thedrupalblog.com/category/tags/exposed-filter) also has something on exposed filters.  I would thoroughly recommend this approach, I've done something very similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: What you say is the first thing I thought and tried. But I need to put the searcher in the home page (a stand along searcher) and not as a sort of header in the view. Plus, I need to search the 'prices' between a range of price. I've already use some exposed filter but nothing like this. I'll take a look to the links you posted above.